# RobotFramework: Using a list of variables in a For loop

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework

I'm facing an issue, that probably is because of my lack of Python knowledge, but I'm trying to verify checkboxes that are contained in a dropdown. Because the web app being developed might contain several of this dropdown lists in different pages I wanted to create a keyword I could use by only passing the generic class of the div and checkbox
At the moment I have the following keywords for this matter:

```
Verify Container Items
    [Documentation]   This keyword should be used on simple list items where the elements can be tested for redirect funtionality.
    ...               Parameters:
    ...                 closed_locator: generic class for the closed container
    ...                 opened_locator: generic class for the opened container
    ...                 locator: generic class for a given web element inside the container
    [Arguments]    ${closed_locator}      ${opened_locator}       ${item_locator}
    ${container_closed_xpath}=    Set Variable       ${closed_locator}
    ${container_opened_xpath}=    Set Variable       ${opened_locator}
    @{container_xpath}=     Create List     ${closed_locator}      ${opened_locator}
    ${container_count}=    get element count       ${container_xpath}
    ${container_names}=    Create List
    FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    1    @{container_count} + 1
        ${element_closed}=    Set Variable       (${container_xpath[0]})[${i}]
        ${element_opened}=    Set Variable       (${container_xpath[1]})[${i}]
        ${name}=    Get Text    xpath=${element[1]}
        Append To List    ${names}    ${name}
        Click Element   ${element_closed}
            Verify Contained Items      ${item_locator}
        Click Element   ${element_opened}
    END


Verify Contained Items
    [Arguments]     ${item_locator}
    ${item_xpath}=    Set Variable       ${item_locator}
    ${item_count}=    get element count       ${item_xpath}
    ${item_names}=    Create List
    FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    1    ${item_count} + 1
        ${element}=    Set Variable       (${item_xpath})[${i}]
        ${name}=    Get Text    xpath=${element}
        Append To List    ${item_names}    ${name}
        Click Element   ${element}
    END
```

This is where my knowledge of python might be screwing me. in the first keyword I pass a xpath for the closed dropdown, opened dropdown which I store in a list which is going to be used in the FOR count, and with this I want it to click on the closed dropdown to open it, call the other keyword to tick all the checkboxes, click on the opened dropdown to close it and increment the values of both closed or opened dropdown and iteract with the other dropdowns/ checkboxes.

However when running the test I get the error:

`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'startswith'`

[image]

At this point I tried it all and I'm stuck in this, I started to do a workaround with other keywords, but I wanted to know if its possible to do it with a list of two variables or if I'm just wasting my time and probably brain cells.

BTW I'm using SeleniumLibrary and Collections libraries and PyCharm to code

Comment: Which keyword gives you that error?

Comment: The error is `${container_count}=    get element count       ${container_xpath}` I forgot to say it. I'll edit the main post

Comment: You're passing a list to `Get Element Count`. It requires a locator string.

Comment: But I'm doing that with `${container_count}=    get element count       ${container_xpath}` My problem is because I'm using a list rather than using individual variables, and I'm asking if I can do it with a list

Comment: No, you can't do it with a list.

Comment: I have to elaborate two keywords and call then in another, thanks